# Overlay images onto Camera preview SurfaceView and how to save them?

Tags: android

I have a SurfaceView that is being used to draw images, and I would like to overlay them onto a live-feed from the phone's camera. I have read [Overlay images onto camera preview surfaceview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548666/overlay-images-onto-camera-preview-surfaceview)
and [how to draw an overlay on a surfaceview used by camera on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933882/how-to-draw-an-overlay-on-a-surfaceview-used-by-camera-on-android)

```
    public class TestCameraOverlayActivity extends Activity { 
         Bitmap bitmap;

         /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
         @Override 
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
               requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
               Preview mPreview = new Preview(this); 
               DrawOnTop mDraw = new DrawOnTop(this); 
               bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
               setContentView(mPreview); 
               addContentView(mDraw, new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        } 

        class DrawOnTop extends View { 
            public DrawOnTop(Context context) { 
                super(context); 

        } 

        @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
            Paint paint = new Paint(); 
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE); 
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
            canvas.drawText("Test Text", 10, 10, paint); 
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
            super.onDraw(canvas); 
        } 
    } 

    class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { 
        SurfaceHolder mHolder; 
        Camera mCamera; 

        Preview(Context context) { 
            super(context); 
            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the 
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed. 
            mHolder = getHolder(); 
            mHolder.addCallback(this); 
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
        } 

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
            // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where 
            // to draw. 
            mCamera = Camera.open(); 
             try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        } 

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
           // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview. 
           // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very 
           // important to release it when the activity is paused. 
           mCamera.stopPreview(); 
           mCamera = null; 
        } 

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) { 
            // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin 
            // the preview. 
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters(); 
            parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h); 
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters); 
            mCamera.startPreview(); 
       } 
    } 
 }
```

if you run it you can one see image on the  preview SurfaceView, but my question is how to save them together as jpeg on the sdcard. Can you give some advice, if i need Format conversion so that i can save them at the same time. My partial solution to save the image only

```
/** Handles data for jpeg picture */
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {

public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
try {
    // write to local sandbox file system
        // outStream = CameraDemo.this.openFileOutput(String.format("%d.jpg", 
           System.currentTimeMillis()), 0); 

        // Or write to sdcard
    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", 
        System.currentTimeMillis()));   
    outStream.write(data);
    outStream.close();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
}
Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
}
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are asking how to merge the two images into one.

The first thing you should do is use an AsynchHandler to save your image so you don't lock up the UI, that's not part of your issue but it will be.

As to your general question it was [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263152/save-image-overlay-with-camera-captured-image-underneith) in general you will need to merge the two image parts together and handle scaling of your overlay as a whole, or the component image parts.

Answer (score 5):

I have created the follow sample code based on this one, which taks the photo and merge it with an overlay image, then save the final image on /sdcard/DCIM/CameraAPIDemo.

It is also integrated with a simple app which could be found here:
https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/RealMadridvsBorussia

```
package com.jiahaoliuliu.android.futbol.realmadridvsborussia;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.renderscript.ProgramVertexFixedFunction.Constants;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PreviewCamera extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = PreviewCamera.class.getSimpleName();
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Preview mPreview;
    private Long topPhotoLong;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */ 
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

          // Get the intent
          Intent startedIntent = getIntent();

          // Get the team
          topPhotoLong = startedIntent.getLongExtra(PhotoGallery.TOP_PHOTO_ID_NAME, new Long(-1));

          if (topPhotoLong > -1) {
              Log.v(LOG_TAG, "The photoId is " + topPhotoLong);
              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), topPhotoLong.intValue());

          } else {
              Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Photo id not found");
          }

          FrameLayout Game = new FrameLayout(this);
          mPreview = new Preview(this); 
          DrawOnTop mDraw = new DrawOnTop(this);
          LinearLayout GameWidgets = new LinearLayout (this);

          Button EndGameButton = new Button(this);
          TextView MyText = new TextView(this);

          EndGameButton.setWidth(1200);
          EndGameButton.setText("Take photo");

          GameWidgets.addView(EndGameButton);

          Game.addView(mPreview);
          Game.addView(GameWidgets);

          setContentView(Game);
          addContentView(mDraw, new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

          EndGameButton.setOnClickListener(this);
          // Lock the screen to landscape
          this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

   } 

   class DrawOnTop extends View { 
       public DrawOnTop(Context context) { 
           super(context); 

   } 

   @Override 
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       if (bitmap != null) {
           canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
       }
       super.onDraw(canvas); 
   } 
} 

   public void onClick(View v) {
       Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Taking picture");
       mPreview.takePicture();
   }

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback { 
   SurfaceHolder mHolder; 
   Camera mCamera; 

   Preview(Context context) { 
       super(context); 
       // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the 
       // underlying surface is created and destroyed. 
       mHolder = getHolder(); 
       mHolder.addCallback(this); 
       mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS); 
   } 

   public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
       // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where 
       // to draw. 
       mCamera = Camera.open();
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }

   public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { 
      // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview. 
      // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very 
      // important to release it when the activity is paused. 
      mCamera.stopPreview(); 
      mCamera = null; 
   }

   public void takePicture() {
       mCamera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
   }

   public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) { 
       // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin 
       // the preview. 
       Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters(); 
       parameters.setPreviewSize(w, h); 
       //mCamera.setParameters(parameters); 
       mCamera.startPreview(); 
  } 
} 
public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {

    private final Context context;

    public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        File sdDir = Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        File pictureFileDir =  new File(sdDir, "/CameraAPIDemo");

        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Can't create directory to save image.");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

        File pictureFile = new File(filename);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // TODO: Merge the photo
            try {
                Bitmap bottomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath()); //blue

                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
                Resources res = getResources();

                Bitmap topImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, topPhotoLong.intValue()); //green
                Drawable drawable1 = new BitmapDrawable(bottomImage);
                Drawable drawable2 = new BitmapDrawable(topImage);


                drawable1.setBounds(0, 0, bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight());
                drawable2.setBounds(0, 0, bottomImage.getWidth(), bottomImage.getHeight());
                drawable1.draw(c);
                drawable2.draw(c);


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            // To write the file out to the SDCard:
            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                os = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, os);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "File" + filename + "not saved: "
                    + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
}
```